# SQL query to get average as below case or how to use hibernate criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

```
Column Mode:   0 1 0 1
Column Value1: 5 6 4 8
Column Value2: 10 7 5 20
```

How to get Avg based on Mode e.g for mode 0 , it will take value from Value1 column and 1 , it will take value from Value2 column

Avg = (5 + 7 + 4 + 20)/4 =9

Comment: Use a `case` expression to chose val1 or val2. Then `AVG()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql `CASE` statement to chose value1 or value2 based upon value of mode.
The below query should work for you.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE
        WHEN mode = 0 THEN value1
        WHEN mode = 1 THEN value2
    END)
FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

below may work

```
 select (val1+val2)/2 from 
    (select sum(case when mode =0 then value1 end) as val1 ,
     sum(case when mode=1 then value2 end) as val2
    ) t
```

Or

```
select avg(case mode when 0 then Value1
                 when 1 then Value2
                   else 0 end) from t
```